# Get value out of Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get a certain value out of an array.
Example of the array is:

```
array(2) {
  ["error"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["result"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["open"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["12345-AAAAA-66AAKK"]=>
      array(14) {
        ["inf"]=>
```

Usually when I want a certain value I would use:

```
$datawanted=$data[result][open][value];
```

However, in this case the first array is a variable that always changes (12345-AAAAA-66AAKK), I need to find the value of that.

I tried getting this with `reset()` and `key[0]` but this not give the wanted result.

Is there a way to get the output of the first element in the result array?

Comment: What are you trying to ask ?

Comment: while dealing with arrays it is preferred to make sure that the keys are static, the values can be non-static

Comment: You can use `array_keys()` to get the keys and use that at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_search: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-search.php

Example:

```
foreach ($array['result']['open'] as $dynamicKey => $item) {
    if ($key = array_search('Value you are looking for', $item) {
       $datawanted=$array['result']['open'][$dynamicKey][$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data[result][open]` is not a correct way to access array items.

The token `result` looks like a constant. PHP searches for a [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) named `result`, cannot find one and triggers a notice. Then it thinks "I guess the programmer wanted to write `'result'` (a string, not a constant). I'll convert it as string to them." and uses `'result'` instead.

It works but it's a horrible practice. It dates from the prehistory of PHP, 20 years ago and [it's not recommended](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar).

After you fix your code to correctly denote the keys of an array, the next step is to pick one of the many PHP ways to access values in the array.

You can get the first value of an array without knowing its key (`$data['result']['open']['12345-AAAAA-66AAKK']`) by using the function [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```
 $datawanted = reset($data['result']['open']);
```

Or you can use the function [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to get only the values of the array (the keys are ignored, the returned array have the values indexed from zero) then your desired data is at position `0` on this array:

```
 $values     = array_values($data['result']['open']);
 $datawanted = $values[0];
```

Another option, if you don't need to keep `$data` for further processing, is to use the PHP function [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to remove the first value from the array and return it. Be warned that this function modifies the array it receives as argument:

```
$datawanted = array_shift($data['result']['open']);
```

If you need to process all the values of `$data['result']['open']` (and you probably do) then the best way is to use the [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) PHP statement. It allows you to access both the key and the value of each element of the array:

```
foreach ($data['result']['open'] as $key => $value) {
    // $key is '12345-AAAAA-66AAKK'
    $datawanted = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have tried the code but unfortunately this just returns 'array' as the result. Both the one with reset() and the foreach statement.

When I echo the results it says Array

Comment: Of course `echo` prints `Array`. The value you want (and get) in `$datawanted` is an array. Use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to investigate its structure and content.

Comment: Right of course, but this still does not give me the value I am looking for. Actually it missed exactly that value as it shows the result of that value. So if I leave out 'open' I will also get the variable, but I do not understand how I can assign that to a variable.